# Wrong output when trying to create a manifest-generating script (python) for Rail-RNA. Files do not match

Tags: python, csv, parsing

**What I want:** To create a "manifest" for running rail-RNA (http://rail.bio/) on a number of fastq files, that I have in a directory, in the following form:

```
FASTQ URL 1 (tab) optional MD5 1 (tab) FASTQ URL 2 (tab) optional MD5 2 (tab) sample label
```

like:

```
/home/data/10080-17_r1.fastq   0   /home/data/10080-17_r2.fastq    0    10080-17_r1
/home/data/10300-25_r1.fastq   0   /home/data/10300-25_r2.fastq    0    10300-25_r1
/home/data/40500-72_r1.fastq   0   /home/data/40500-72_r2.fastq    0    10300-25_r2
```

.. and so on

**What I have done:** created a python script to generate a manifest from fastq files in a specific directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import csv    

thisdir = os.getcwd()

# Create empty lists
forward = []
reverse = []
zero = []
names = []

# Extract file-paths for files ending with .fastq and append them to "forward" and "reverse"
for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for file in f:
        if "_1.fastq" in file:
            forward.append(os.path.join(r, file))
        if "_2.fastq" in file:
            reverse.append(os.path.join(r, file))

# make a list containing 0 with the length of the forward list
for i in range(len(forward)):
    zero.append('0')

# extract filenames without extensions:
l = os.listdir(thisdir)
li = [x.split('.')[0] for x in l]
for name in li:
    if "_1" in name:
        names.append(name)
names = [s.strip('_1') for s in names]

# write the output to a file
with open('manifest.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for path in zip(forward, zero, reverse, zero, names):
        writer.writerow(list(path))
```

**What is wrong?**: I get a manifest.txt in the right format, BUT, it does not match the right *_r1.fastq and *_r2.fastq files. It does something like this (the r1's in the first column does not match the r2's of the third column)

```
/home/data/10080-17_r1.fastq   0   /home/data/40500-72_r2.fastq    0    10080-17_r1
/home/data/10300-25_r1.fastq   0   /home/data/10080-17_r2.fastq    0    10300-25_r1
/home/data/40500-72_r1.fastq   0   /home/data/10300-25_r2.fastq    0    10300-25_r2
```

Do some of you, more experienced Python'ers have a solution to fix this? 
That would be greatly appreciated!

Best wishes, Birgitte

Comment: Hi Birgitte, I'm struggling to make out what's going on there, sorry. If you could provide an example list of filenames - nothing you've indicated there has an `"_1"` or `"_2"` in it?
e.g. `"_1.fastq"` vs `"/home/data/10080-17_r1.fastq"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In provided solution this error occurs if amount of *_r1.fastq files doesn't correspond to amount of *_r2.fastq files as that code makes new csv rows only by arrays indexes and doesn't compare file names. 
I updated that solution. Check the files names, they are should be like:

> /home/data/10080-17_r1.fastq 
>   /home/data/10080-17_r2.fastq

At the moment we get all forward files ( *_r1.fastq ) and we are trying to find an appropriate reverse file 
 ( *_r2.fastq) in the same directory. If we doesn't find it then put '-' instead of the reverse file's name. 
Please check the code and read comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import csv

this_dir = os.getcwd()
forward_arr = []
reverse_arr = [] 

for r, d, f in os.walk(this_dir):    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for file in f:
        if "_r1.fastq" in file:
            forward_arr.append(os.path.join(r, file))
        if "_r2.fastq" in file:
            reverse_arr.append(os.path.join(r, file))

# collect result rows in this array
csv_arr = []
# foreach file in forward_arr
for forward_file in forward_arr:
    # get sample label from full file path
    # 1. split by '/' and select last element:
    # /home/data/10080-17_r1.fastq -> 10080-17_r1.fastq
    # 2. split by '_r' and select first element: 10080-17_r1.fastq -> 10080-17
    sample_label = forward_file.split('/')[-1].split('_r')[0]
    # we will search the reverse file for the same forward file in the reverse_arr
    # but if we don't find it, in that case we'll put '-'
    # instead of the path to the reverse file
    reverse_file_result = "-"
    # we are looking for a file with the same name and in the same location
    # but it should be a reverse file with '_r2' instead of '_r1' in its name
    reverse_file_for_search = forward_file.replace("_r1", "_r2")
    # search that reverse_file in the reverse_arr
    for reverse_file in reverse_arr:
        # if we found that file
        if reverse_file_for_search == reverse_file:
            # assign the reverse file name 
            # to reverse_file_result variable insted of '-'
            reverse_file_result = reverse_file
            # go to the next forward_file
            break
    # in that place we can count md5 for the FORWARD file
    md5_url_1 = 0
    # in that place we can count md5 for the REVERSE file
    md5_url_2 = 0
    # append the result row in the csv_arr
    csv_arr.append((forward_file, md5_url_1, reverse_file_result,
                    md5_url_2, sample_label))

# re-write all data to csv file per one iteration
with open('manifest.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(csv_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for what you need. It's difficult to make out, because this:

`names = [s.strip('_1') for s in names]`

doesn't look like it should be doing anything (I suspect it's supposed to be "_r1" as in the first loop where I've modified there)

```
import os
import csv    

thisdir = os.getcwd()

# Create empty lists
forward = []
reverse = []
names = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    if f.endswith("_r1.fastq"):
        forward.append(os.path.join(r, file))
        names.append(f.strip("_r1.fastq"))
    elif f.endswith("_r2.fastq"):
        reverse.append(os.path.join(r, file))


# write the output to a file
with open('manifest.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for for, rev, nam in zip(forward, reverse, names):
        path = [for, 0, rev, o, nam]
        writer.writerow(path)
```